# Unrecognised name when using COALESCE in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm writing a standard query to run across various different tables in BigQuery.

Some tables will have data on transactions, and others won't.

It's important that my final table includes the transactions column, even if the key doesn't exist in the source.

I want to use COALESCE to check if the transaction key exists, and use 0 as the value if not.

```sql
#standardSQL
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT('googleanalytics',FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", DATETIME(date, "UTC")),devicecategory,sourcemedium,campaign) as key,
    'Google Analytics' as data_source,
    sessions,
    pageviews,
    bounces,
    COALESCE(transactions,0) as transactions,
    goalcompletionsall,
  FROM
     `project.datasource.table`
)
```

When my source table doesn't include a 'transactions' key I expect the query to run, but use 0 as the value.

Instead, I get an error:

> Unrecognized name: transactions at [10:13]

I understand why this is happening, but I need to get around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and can give you an idea/direction.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_transactions(t ANY TYPE) AS (
  IFNULL(CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"transactions":(\d+)') AS INT64), 0)
);
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 col1, 3 col2, 4 col3, 12 transactions 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 2 id, 3 col1, 4 col2, 5 col3
)
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, get_transactions(t) AS transactions
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, get_transactions(t) AS transactions
FROM `project.dataset.table2` t
```

Meantime, interesting feature of Legacy SQL allows you to do a trick with COALESCE as in below example

```
#legacySQL
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, COALESCE(transactions,0) AS transactions
FROM [project:dataset.table1], [project:dataset.table2]
```

Note: comma between tables in legacy SQL means UNION ALL

If to mimic same samplified data

```
#legacySQL
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, COALESCE(transactions,0) AS transactions
FROM (
  SELECT 1 id, 2 col1, 3 col2, 4 col3, 12 transactions
), (
  SELECT 2 id, 3 col1, 4 col2, 5 col3
)
```

result will be same as in example for standardSQL

```
Row id  col1    col2    col3    transactions     
1   1   2       3       4       12   
2   2   3       4       5       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias the table and then refer to `transactions` using that alias:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('googleanalytics', FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y%m%d', DATETIME(t.date, 'UTC')),
        t.devicecategory, t.sourcemedium, t.campaign) AS key,
    'Google Analytics' AS data_source,
    t.sessions,
    t.pageviews,
    t.bounces,
    COALESCE(t.transactions, 0) AS transactions,
    t.goalcompletionsall
FROM `project.datasource.table` t;
```

Comment: Thanks - the alias works (wasn't aware of that function) but still getting a similar issue `Name transactions not found inside t`

Comment: Well does your table have a column called `transactions`?

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be writing queries using columns that are not in tables.  I would recommend fixing the tables.

But, if your table has a primary key (logically of course in BQ), you can use the following scoping trick:

```
select . . .,
       (select (select transactions  -- NO alias!  This is to trick scoping
                from `project.datasource.table` t2
                where t2.primary_key = t.primary_key
               )
        from (select 0 as transactions) tr 
       ) as transactions
from `project.datasource.table` t;
```

Note:  I have used this in other databases, but have not specifically used this in BigQuery.